# Scenario on Teradata Joins

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two source tables

MST

```
CustNo  Date
C1  P1
C1  P2
C1  P3
C1  P4
C1  P5
C1  P6
```

TMP

```
CustNo  Rule    Amt Date
C1  R1  A1  P1
C1  R1  A2  P2
C1  R1  A3  P3
```

I want my result table as

```
CustNo  Rule    Amt Date
C1  R1  A1  P1
C1  R1  A2  P2
C1  R1  A3  P3
C1  R1  0   P4
C1  R1  0   P5
C1  R1  0   P6
```

Can any help me how this can be achieved in TD

Answer (score 0):

Use this. But it will not give you `R1` for all the rows.

```
select
m.CustNo,t.Rule,
case when t.Amt is null 
    then 0 
    else t.Amt 
end as Rule
,m.Date
from MST m
left join
TMP t
on m.Date=t.Date
```

There is no relation between `P4` and 'R1`, but if you just want to Hardcode`R1`with`C1`, you can use it in`select` query.

Comment: I tried. Not working. I am not getting P4, P5, P6 in my output

Comment: Show the output and the exact query you ran. As per definition of Left Join you should get everything from left table(MST in this case)

Comment: Qusery :  SEL 
 MST.WH_CUST_NO
 ,TMP.AGG_RULE_NAME
 , CASE WHEN TMP.BAL_AMT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TMP.BAL_AMT END AS BAL_AMT
 ,MST.PERIOD_DTE
 FROM
 DDEWD03S.MASTER_LST_TEST2 MST
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    DDEWD03S.CUST_BAL_SUMM_TMP1 TMP
  ON
  --MST.WH_CUST_NO = TMP.WH_CUST_NO  AND 
  MST.PERIOD_DTE = TMP.PERIOD_DTe

Comment: Output                                                                         : 1  R1 -574.33 31/05/2016
1 R1 -2017.94 29/07/2016
1 R1 -929.27 29/04/2016

Comment: if u are joining on `PERIOD_DTE`, then as per Output, it looks that MST has only 3 `PERIOD_DTE` .

Comment: Your query  does that : select
m.CustNo,t.Rule,
case when t.Amt is null 
    then 0 
    else t.Amt 
end as Rule
,m.Date
from MST m
left join
TMP t
on **m.Date=t.Date**

Answer (score 0):

```
select    a.custno,coalesce(b.rule,'R1') as rule,amt,a.date
from      mst a
leftjoin  tmp b
       on a.cust_date=b.cust_date
      and a.cust_no = b.cust_no
```

Comment: Please add an explaination and use the format tags to be more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
select
m.CustNo,COALESCE(t.RULE, 'R1' ),
case when t.Amt is null 
    then 0 
    else t.Amt 
end as amt
,m.Date1
from d1t_tmp.customer1 m
left join
d1t_tmp.customer2 t
on m.Date1=t.Date1
ORDER BY M.DATE1
```